# Excel select rows with missing data and copy the selected rows

Tags: excel

I have a big excel file with info of companies and there companyID.
But some companies miss there companyID. So I need to copy dose rows, but I cant find how to do that.

```
So in this exampel I want copy row 2 and 4 
    A         B             
 Company  CompanyID    
1 asd        123
2 sda
3 ads        321
4 sad
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. filter the column B (*CompanyID*) where = blank and copy the results into another sheet.
2. select the entire columns A and B, the insert a pivot table with *Company* and *CompanyID* in ROWS. Then FIlter the results to show only the rows where *CompanyID* is blank.

The second one is more interactive, you just have to refresh the pivot table to get the updated results. Of course, it depends on how many times you have to to this job and how many times the list is being updated.

Answer (score -1):

select all data company name field and company id field.then select filter and sort button in excell.then  click company id header  and click number filter and then equal and ok

Comment: No I dont want to add, I need to copy the rows with missing companyID, so I can make a new excel file, and ask the customer to fill in the missing info in ColumnB, but they gonna need the company name (ColumnA) to do that

Comment: select all data company name field and company id field.then select filter and sort button in excell.then click company id header and click text filter and then equal and ok